# ERRO : CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public boolean insertData(int id_pedido, int id_item, String nome, int quantidade) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1_ITEM_ORDER, id_pedido);
    contentValues.put(COL_2_ITEM_ORDER, id_item);
    contentValues.put(COL_3_ITEM_ORDER, nome);
    contentValues.put(COL_4_ITEM_ORDER, quantidade);
    String sql = "SELECT preco FROM " + TABLE_PRECO + " WHERE id_item = " + id_item;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String preco_unitario = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_3_PRICES));
    cursor.close();
    double total = quantidade * Long.parseLong(preco_unitario);
    contentValues.put(COL_5_ITEM_ORDER, preco_unitario);
    contentValues.put(COL_6_ITEM_ORDER, total);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_ITEM_PEDIDO, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

> ERRO : android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0
>   requested, with a size of 0

Alguém pode me auxiliar por favor? Já fiz várias mudanças e nada.

Comment: Pode dizer em que linha está o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Gabriel,

Provavelmente isso acontece porque sua tabela ainda esta vazia, tente fazer assim:

```
if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
  String preco_unitario = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_3_PRICES));
}
```

Abraços.

Comment: E ai Leandro! Era isso mesmo que voce falou , minha tabela estava vazia. Valeu pela força. Funcionou legal agora.